# Doctrine iterate seems flaky

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

As I discovered in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10756852/doctrine-findby-out-of-memory-error), loading 300k rows as entities with Doctrine is not a good idea and will consume at least a gigabyte of memory.

Since I needed some bitwise operations anyway, I figured I'd use a `NativeQuery` and `iterate()` over the result. However, after the first row, my value is always empty. My code is highly similar to [the documentation](http://readthedocs.org/docs/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/batch-processing.html#iterating-large-results-for-data-processing):

```
$sql = "SELECT `pushToken` FROM `Devices`";
$rsm = new Doctrine\ORM\Query\ResultSetMappingBuilder(self::$entityManager);
$rsm->addScalarResult("pushToken", "pt");
$query = self::$entityManager->createNativeQuery($sql, $rsm);
$iterableDevices = $query->iterate();
foreach ($iterableDevices as $row)
{
    $message->addRecipient($row[0]["pt"]);
}
```

When I `var_dump`'ed `$row` however, I noticed that the index is actually incremented each time the code runs through the loop. This is contradicting the documentation. Am I doing something wrong, or have I discovered an honest mistake?

Comment: Have you tried iterating using the while-loop based approach shown in the second to last example on that manual page? I used that one, although with a DQL query, which worked just fine.

Comment: Yes, I just tested it and it gives the same 'strange' result.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution here [Merge all sub arrays into one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27304024/merge-all-sub-arrays-into-one) and did like that:

```
$iterator = $this->getEntityManager()->createNativeQuery($sql, $rsm)->iterate();
foreach ($iterator as $row) {
    yield call_user_func_array('array_merge', $row);
}
```