# Merge all sub arrays into one

Tags: php, arrays

I'm looking to find a way to merge all child arrays into one large array.

```
array (
    [0] = 
         [0] = '0ARRAY',
         [1] = '1ARRAY'
    [1] = 
         [0] = '2ARRAY',
         [1] = '3ARRAY'
)
```

into

```
array (
    [0] = '0ARRAY', [1] = '1ARRAY', [2] = '2ARRAY', [3] = '3ARRAY'
)
```

Without using `array_merge($array[0],$array[1])` because I don't know how many arrays there actually are. So I wouldn't be able to specify them.

Thanks

Answer (score 37, accepted):

If it's only two levels of array, you can use

```
$result = call_user_func_array('array_merge', $array);
```

which should work as long as $array isn't completely empty

Comment: Best solution if found too : $array is then used as a list or arguments to the [array_merge() function](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.call-user-func-array.php)

Comment: With fix for empty $array: `$result = call_user_func_array('array_merge', $array ?: [[]]);`

Comment: php8 Fatal error:  Uncaught ArgumentCountError: array_merge() does not accept unknown named parameters

Answer (score 51):

If I understood your question:

php 5.6+

```
$array = array(
  array('first', 'second'),
  array('next', 'more')
);
$newArray = array_merge(...$array);
```

Outputs:

```
array(4) { [0]=> string(5) "first" [1]=> string(6) "second" [2]=> string(4) "next" [3]=> string(4) "more" }
```

Example: http://3v4l.org/KA5J1#v560

php < 5.6

```
$newArray = call_user_func_array('array_merge', $array);
```

Comment: If anyone intrested where `...` "splat" operator is documented: regarding general issue - "Argument Unpacking" https://wiki.php.net/rfc/argument_unpacking , official mention is also here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration56.new-features.php

Comment: With fix for empty $array: `$newArray = array_merge(...$array ?: [[]]);`

Answer (score 3):

```
$new_array = array();
foreach($main_array as $ma){
    if(!empty($ma)){
        foreach($ma as $a){
            array_push($new_array, $a);
        }
    }
}
```

You can try it by placing these values:

```
$main_array[0][0] = '1';
$main_array[0][1] = '2';
$main_array[1][0] = '3';
$main_array[1][1] = '4';
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 3 [3] => 4 )
```