# A simple way to get a single array containing all the integers that are contained within a nested object in PHP

Tags: php

I have the following structure:

```
  {
    "produto_id" : 54,
    "descricao_id" : 25,
    "contas" : [
        {
            "marketplace_id" : 8,
            "contas_ids" : [
                 6, 8, 9
                ]
        },
        {
            "marketplace_id" : 9,
            "contas_ids" : [
                 44, 100
                ]
        }
        ]
}
```

I want to get an array contained all the "contas_ids" like this:

```
  [6, 8, 9, 44, 100]
```

I've tried array_map but I had to use so many. With array_column I achieve something close but it divided the output in several arrays.

```
 $ids = array_column($contas,  'contas_ids');
```

using "dd" I get this.

```
   array:2 [
  0 => array:3 [
    0 => 6
    1 => 8
    2 => 9
  ]
  1 => array:2 [
    0 => 44
    1 => 100
  ]
]
```

Can someone help me produce a single array with all "contas_id"?

Comment: @ggorlen looks like valid JSON to me.

Comment: You're right. Even so, it's not clear what `$contas` is--is it the full structure or just the subarray? Adding the parsing code would be helpful as part of a [mcve].

Comment: @ggorlen Agreed, looks like it's just the `contas` array. That's what I assumed in my answer.

Comment: You mentioned using dd, is this in a Laravel app? If that data comes from a query, there's probably a better way to do this.

Comment: Why is this json invalid? I am getting this json from a post request.

Answer (score 0):

After you get the sub-arrays with `$ids = array_column($contas,  'contas_ids');`, you can combine the arrays using `array_merge`, as outlined in this question: [Merge all sub arrays into one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27304024/merge-all-sub-arrays-into-one)

```
call_user_func_array("array_merge", $ids);
```

Answer (score 0):

This should get you what you need.

```
$json = '{
    "produto_id" : 54,
    "descricao_id" : 25,
    "contas" : [{
        "marketplace_id" : 8,
        "contas_ids" : [ 6, 8, 9 ]
    },
    {
            "marketplace_id" : 9,
            "contas_ids" : [ 44, 100 ]
    }
    ]
}
';

$ids=[];
foreach(json_decode($json,true)['contas'] as $key => $val){
    $ids = array_merge($ids, $val['contas_ids']);
}
var_dump($ids);
```

Answer (score 0):

One more `array_merge()` solution, but this time with an [obscure operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration56.new-features.php#migration56.new-features.splat)!

```
<?php
$json = '{
    "produto_id" : 54,
    "descricao_id" : 25,
    "contas" : [
        {
            "marketplace_id" : 8,
            "contas_ids" : [
                 6, 8, 9
                ]
        },
        {
            "marketplace_id" : 9,
            "contas_ids" : [
                 44, 100
                ]
        }
        ]
}';
$contas = json_decode($json, true);
$ids = array_column($contas["contas"], "contas_ids");
$integers = array_merge(...$ids);
print_r($integers);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 6
    [1] => 8
    [2] => 9
    [3] => 44
    [4] => 100
)
```